# Rails: array is blank if one field is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Why would this return blank if just one field is left unfilled? Doesn't make any sense to me.

```
def api_user_information
  user_information = "#{user.address}\n\n"
  user_information << "<b>P</b> #{user.phone}\n" unless user.phone.blank?
  user_information << "<b>F</b> #{user.fax}\n" unless user.fax.blank?
  user_information << "<b>M</b> #{user.mobile}\n" unless user.mobile.blank?
  user_information << "<b>E</b> #{user.email}\n" unless user.email.blank?
  user_information << "<b>W</b> #{user.url}\n" unless user.url.blank?
  user_information << "<b>Facebook</b> #{user.facebook}\n" unless user.facebook.blank?
  user_information << "<b>Twitter</b> @#{user.twitter}" unless user.twitter.blank?
end
```

Comment: what have you find inside params? 
you can use if user.phone.present?

Comment: post the output of user.inspect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last statment result is your return value of the method. So the return value is result of

```
user_information << "<b>Twitter</b> @#{user.twitter}" unless user.twitter.blank?
```

if "user.twitter.blank?" is ture, "user_information << "**Twitter** @#{user.twitter}" is never reached. It might return "nil".

How about add

```
user_information
```

or

```
return user_information
```

in your last line of the method and see the result.

Comment: To add to your correct answer; the value should be `nil` in the case where `user.twitter.blank?` returns `true`. From irb: `[] << 1 unless true # => nil`

Comment: You are right. I also tested in irb. But didn't modified it because of lazy. I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Genius. Thanks heaps!